# JHipster and Angular - Live Edit Table - Template-driven form

Tags: angular, jhipster

**Goal**

Using JHipster 5.0 Angular 6.0

arrayOfArrays[i] is a list of Objects named Details. Each Detail (named arrayOfArray in the *ngFor directive) contains an id, a quantity and other objects and properties. I created a row per list of Details and a td for each Detail and I would like to live edit this table. More specifically, I would like to live edit the "arrayOfArray.quantite". In turn, I would like to send back each arrayOfArray with its updated quantity to the server.

The put request method I created requires an ArrayList of Detail. 
The Detailservice contains a method updateDetails which normally send this ArrayList of Detail to the put request method. This method is supposed to be called by the method saveDetails itself called by a click in the front.

```
saveDetails(){
    this.DetailService.updateDetails(this.details);
}
```

**Issue**

I don't succeed to generate the ArrayList from the form I created to be able to pass it in updateDetails(this.details). I thought that the steps could be:

1 - In the ts, I create an empty details: ArrayList. Each time I leave a td (with tab or by click =>  by replacing (ngOnSubmit) by something else? but what?), the activated method would get the Detail  together with updated quantity and push it in the Array.

2 -Then a click on the save button would pass the detauksArrayList to the method updateDetails.

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div class="table-responsive" *ngIf="map">
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" *ngIf="arrayOfArrays">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th> Type Mission </th>
            <th *ngFor="let arrayOfArray of arrayOfArrays[0] ;trackBy: 
trackId;"> {{arrayOfArray.jourDuMois  | date:'EEEEE d'}} </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <tr  *ngFor="let keyOfMap of keysOfMap ;trackBy: trackId; let i= 
index" >
                <td> {{keyOfMap}} </td>
                <td *ngFor="let arrayOfArray of arrayOfArrays[i] ;trackBy: 
trackId; let f = index "  >
                    <form name="detailsForm" role="form" 
(ngSubmit)="onSubmitForm()">
                    <input class = "form-control-plaintext" name="quantite" 
id="quantite"[(ngModel)]="arrayOfArray.quantite">
                    </form>
                </td>
        </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>
 <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="saveDetails()"> <fa-icon 
[icon]="'save'"></fa-icon> Sauver </button>
</div>
```

An alternative would have been to create a form for each list of details but I can't make it appear correctly in the front.

Also, in the JHipster, I don't see the formBuilder and formGroup annotation in the update component (as we normally see in Angular generally). Where are they? How does the ts knows which form to get in the html since its not declared or initialized in the corresponding ts?

Could you help me, please?

Thanks

Comment: JHipster uses Angular template-driven forms, see https://angular.io/guide/forms#template-driven-forms) FormBuilder
 is for reactive forms.

Comment: Oh thanks for the template-driven form. I don't know why I was so certain of the reactive form use besides the fact that I couldn't see any markers of this.